# While installing thriftAPI i got this proplem

Tags: apache-2.2

```
C:\Cassandra\java>ant
Buildfile: C:\Cassandra\java\build.xml

setup.init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Cassandra\java\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Cassandra\java\build\lib
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Cassandra\java\build\tools
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Cassandra\java\build\test

ivy.check:

ivy.download:

ivy.init:

mvn.ant.tasks.download:
      [get] Getting: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-ta
sks/2.1.1/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar
      [get] To: C:\Cassandra\java\build\tools\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar
      [get] Error getting http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-a
nt-tasks/2.1.1/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar to C:\Cassandra\java\build\tools\maven-
ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar

BUILD FAILED
C:\Cassandra\java\build.xml:285: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to ho
st: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:233)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:860)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:801)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:726)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.openConnection(Get.java:6
60)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.get(Get.java:579)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.run(Get.java:569)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Wow, you **spoil** us with detail. Care to share what you've done to troubleshoot the problem already?

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to connect a socket to a remote address and port which can't be found.

- Is you internet-access OK?
- Is there another component to this application?
- Is your firewall configured?